# Is XML declarative language?

Tags: xml, declarative

I haven't found a satisfactory answer to this question. Somewhere I see that it was a declarative one and afterward XML Programming Language was written. Please clarify.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the term _declarative_ really does apply here. The primary purpose of XML is the presentation of data, not the execution of algorithms.

Comment: XML is more a *metalanguage* than a *language* itself. It's a kind of toolbox for building actual languages, such as XHTML, XSLT, ODF etc.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out by @Codor, XML itself is just a way to describe/annotate data, this is why it's called e**X**tensible **M**arkup **L**anguage.

Same time, there are some derived technologies that can be named "programming language", more or less. Most famous example here is XSLT: XML transformation that uses special set of rules (XSL stylesheets) to process XML data to another format. So, XSL/XSLT can be named declarative programming language (same time, it is flexible enough and can be used procedural way too).